# File downloads only for .txt .log .svg but fails for .xlsx .xls .gif .docx etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts

I am writing a code in Struts 2.5 where user can download files they uploaded using AJAX. It is working for `.txt`, `.log`, `.rtf` and `.svg` files only.

Files like `.xls`, `.doc` and `.gif` are getting downloaded but they are not opening and showing corrupt. I don't have the privilege to share code of my organisation.

I am also using download.js and header content type is for response application/octet-stream. Using download.bind

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
  url: "myURL?&filePath=" + $(name).html() + "&fileName=" + $(name).html().split(/[\/]/).pop(),
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
  success: function(data) {
    if (data.includes("OK")) {
      console.log("Upload Passed");
    } else {
      console.log("Upload failed");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `...they are not opening and showing corrupt` This is because AJAX downloads content as text. The file types you mention as 'not working' are because they are binary file types. They are also not corrupt, you're just seeing the ASCII representation of their binary content. If you want to view them through a text response from an AJAX request, base64 encode them on the server before sending the response.

Comment: Rory you are right

Answer (score 1):

Solved it... Previously was using.

```
`$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                url: "url?&filePath="+$(name).html()+"&fileName="+$(name).html().split(/[\\\/]/).pop(),
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.includes("OK")) {
                        console.log("Upload Passed");
                    }else{
                        console.log("Upload failed");
                    }


                }
            });`
```

This cause the response in binary to be text which confused

```
`var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST",url,true);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4) {
            if(this.status == 200) {
                console.log(typeof this.response); // should be a blob
                    var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
                  var fileName = "test.pdf";
                  saveAs(blob, fileName);
            } else if(this.responseText != "") {
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
        } else if(this.readyState == 2) {
            if(this.status == 200) {
                this.responseType = "blob";
            } else {
                this.responseType = "text";
            }
        }
    };
ajax.send(json);`
```